# How to calculate the correlation for several files?

Tags: r, binary, correlation

There are  365 binary files in two directories dir1 and dir2, which have the same format ,byte,extend,etc ...

The code given below will  read in dir1 and dir2 as vector and then calculate the correlation.
 basically I want To get the correlation map, we just calculate the R value for each grid pixel. Assuming we want to calculate the global correlation map between dir1 and dir2, we have two columns data from dir1 and dir2 for each pixel and can calculate R value for that pixel, and then simply do a loop on the global pixels.

```
dir1 <- list.files("C:\\cor", "*.bin", full.names = TRUE)
dir2 <- list.files("C:\\cor2", "*.bin", full.names = TRUE)
results <- list()
    for (.files in dir1){
# read in the 365 files as a vector of numbers for dir1
    file1 <- do.call(rbind,(lapply(.files, readBin  , integer() , size = 2 ,
                                n = 360 * 720 , signed = T)))
    }
    for (.files in dir2){
    # read in the 365 files as a vector of numbers for dir2
    file2<- do.call(rbind,(lapply(.files, readBin  , integer() , size = 2 , 
                    n = 360 * 720 , signed = T)))
    }
    # calculate the  correlation so we will get a correlation map
for (.files in seq_along(dir1)){              
    results[[length(results) + 1L]]<- cor(file1 ,file2)
    }
```

I got this error: `Error in cor(file1, file2) : allocMatrix: too many elements specified`

Comment: @Downvoter: Downvoting without a comment is not helpful.

Comment: In what way are `files.group` and `files.group2` different from `dir1` and `dir2`?

Comment: could you show what `file1` and `file2` looks like (using `dput`, `head` or `str`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite your code the following way (assuming I understood correctly and what you want to do is compare each row of `file1` with each row of `file2`):

```
dir1 <- list.files("C:\\cor", "*.bin", full.names = TRUE)
dir2 <- list.files("C:\\cor2", "*.bin", full.names = TRUE)
file1 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(dir1, readBin  , integer() , size = 2 ,
                                n = 360 * 720 , signed = T))
file2 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(dir2, readBin  , integer() , size = 2 ,
                                n = 360 * 720 , signed = T))
results <- apply(file1, 1, function(x){ apply(file2, 1, function(X){cor(x, X)})})
```

`results` will be a matrix (365 x 365) such as the correlation coefficient between your x-th row of file1 (hence, the x-th file in dir1) and y-th row of file2 (hence, the y-th file in dir2) is `results[x,y]`. You can then plot it as an heatmap directly with function `image(results)`.

**Edit:** To clarify the last line of the code: it corresponds exactly to the following `for` loop:

```
results <- array(dim = c(length(file1), length(file2)))
for(i in 1:length(file1)){
    for(j in 1:length(file2)){
        results[i,j]<-cor(file1[i, ], file2[j, ])
        }
    }
```

**Edited as per comments:** @PaulHiemstra was quicker than me, but indeed I was about to propose something similar:

```
dir1 <- list.files("C:\\cor", "*.bin", full.names = TRUE)
dir2 <- list.files("C:\\cor2", "*.bin", full.names = TRUE)
file_tot<-array(dim=c(360,720,365,2))
for(i in 1:length(dir1)){
    file_tot[,,i,1] <- readBin(dir1[i], integer(), size = 2 ,n = 360 * 720 , signed = T)
    file_tot[,,i,2] <- readBin(dir2[i], integer(), size = 2 ,n = 360 * 720 , signed = T)
    }
results<-apply(file_tot,c(1,2),function(x){cor(x[,1],x[,2])})
```

Comment: no it's not normal; but then again, i can't test it because I don't have your files, nor any similar files.

Comment: You said there was 365 files in each directories. So the result of the correlation between the files from each directories has to be 365x365. Or else I misunderstood your question.

Comment: So what do you want to correlate?

Comment: Probably the temporal correlation between the two datasets, i.e. iterate over each x,y location and calculate `cor(dat1_xy, dat2_xy)`.

Comment: Ok, I get it. I'LL try to think about it and come back with something more appropriate.

Comment: The simplest approach is probably to just get it all into memory, and use `apply` on a multi-dimensional `array` (see my answer). The syntax becomes really nice then. The problem could be RAM space, but that can be solved by processing the data in chunks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to calculate the temporal correlation (as it seems) for each x,y location, I would read it into a multi-dimensional array with dimensions `(nx, ny, ntsteps, ndatasets)`, e.g. with a smaller example dataset:

```
          # nx   ny   nsteps ndatasets
dat = runif(20 * 30 * 100 *  2)
dim(dat) = c(20, 30, 100, 2)
> str(dat)
num [1:20, 1:30, 1:100, 1:2] 0.969 0.482 0.974 0.682 0.856 ...
```

Now we take advantage of the fact that `apply` also works on multi-dimensional arrays, not only matrices:

```
cor_result = apply(dat, c(1,2), function(x) cor(x[,1], x[,2]))
> str(cor_result)
 num [1:20, 1:30] 0.06673 0.00943 -0.11265 -0.01157 -0.0024 ...
```

We use `apply` to iterate over all the x,y pairs to calculate the temporal correlation.

In regard to your big dataset, loading it would take approx 1.4 Gb. The rule of thumb in R is that you need 3 times the dataset size as RAM to be able to work with it. So if you've got, say, 8 Gb of RAM and a 64 bit R this should work fine. Alternatively, I often do these calculations in chunks as I have only 4 Gb. For example, you can first process the first 5 rows (y-coordinate), than the second 5 etc.